# Searching required  data in couchdb

Tags: couchdb

I have documents like,

```
{_id:1,
name:"john"
}
{_id:2,
name:"john boss"
}
{_id:3,
name:"jim"
}
```

I have to search the data where ever john is stored in documents. Suppose, if i search "john" the documents should get _id:1 & _id:2 related data. Please guide me to get the result.

I appreciate if any one provide the solutions.

Comment: Did you try anything before asking? Please show your attempt first.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a [CouchDB view](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views) to show you all "words" from the `"name`" field.

```
function(doc) {
    // map function: _design/example/_view/names

    if(!doc.name) // Optionally do more testing for doc type, etc. here.
        return

    // Emit one row per word in the name field (first name, last name, etc.).
    var words = doc.name.split(/\s+/)
    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        emit(words[i].toLowerCase(), doc._id)
}
```

Now if you query `/db/_design/example/_view/names?key="john"`, you will get two rows: one for doc id 1, and another for id 2. I also added a conversion to lower case, so searching for "john" will match people named "John".

Duplicates are possible: the same doc ID listed multiple times, e.g. for `{"name":"John John"}`; however you are guaranteed that all duplicate rows will be adjacent.

You can also add `?include_docs=true` to your request to get the full document for each row.